# THETA token sent to contract address instead of correct wallet address

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ether, etherscan, myetherwallet

By mistake, I sent my THETA token to the contract address instead of my correct wallet address.
This is the transaction link on Etherscan https://etherscan.io/tx/0x564fe4eb2853adc6375c75e80c2c2c67be2507f81fa540f28944339ec50b366e

The contract address I send my tokens by mistake is **0x3883f5e181fccaf8410fa61e12b59bad963fb645**. You can see the details in the Etherscan transaction link I shared above. Is there any way I can get back my THETA tokens? I tried to get in touch with THETA team on telegram (https://t.me/thetanetwork) but it is full of spammers who are trying to dupe you.

I will appreciate if any one can point me in a direction which could help me get back my THETA token.

Comment: Hi did you ever figure out what happened to your theta tokens , the same thing just happened to me and wondering what to do

Comment: so my reply comes a bit late but I got in touch with the THETA team and they mentioned, tokens send to the wrong address are lost forever .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot retrieve funds if you sent them to the contract address instead of the intended recipient.

Comment: but the contract address seems to belong to THETA network itself. is there no way they can return me back my tokens. thanks in advance